# Is the this Hankel matrix positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Consider a Hankel matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n, n}$ with the following elements

$$h_{ij} = -\frac{4}{i+j} \quad \text{if } \quad i+j = \text{even}\\
h_{ij} = \frac{2}{i+j+1} + \frac{2}{i+j-1} \quad \text{if } \quad i+j = \text{odd}$$

Can we show that this matrix is PSD?

I implemented this matrix for different $n$ and computed the eigenvalues. Up to $n=12$, all eigenvalues are greater than zero. However, starting from $n=13$, some very small eigenvalues start to appear (of order $10^{-17}$). I suspect that this might be due to numerical stability since this also happens when computing the eigenvalues of the Hilbert matrix which we know is positive definite.

Edit:
Thanks to the comment below, I realized that I made a mistake in the code and the matrix is not PSD (easily seen for $n=1$).

Comment: So $h_{1,1}=-2$ and all the other diagonal entries are negative, too? How can this be PSD?

Comment: @kimchilover Good point! I've made a mistake in my code.